# Sorting elements in a nested XSLT for-each loop

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt, foreach

I'm creating a bulleted list of sorted titles, using XSLT transformation from XML to HTML.

Right now I am printing out each of the titles in an unsorted manner:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>This file contains correspondence: </p>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ead/archdesc/dsc/c01">
                        <xsl:for-each select="c02">                        
                            <li><xsl:value-of select="did/unittitle"/></li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

Each c02 element is contained within a c01 element, of which there are many. So if I put my xsl:sort element inside the second foreach loop, sorting on the unittitles, each c02 element is being sorted individually, not the full list.

My output when placing the sorting element in the second for-each loop resets the sorting after each c01 element.

```
         <li>Kuiper</li>
         <li>Oort</li>
         <li>Oosterhoff</li>
         <li>Schlesinger</li>
         <li>Shapley</li>
         <li>Sitter, A. de</li>
         <li>Tisdale</li>
         <li>Van Gent</li>
         <li>Bosscha Observatory</li> //Sorting resets
```

My question is how I can sort the entire list of elements, when I have nested for-each loops in this case.

Edit: XML Source snippet

```
<dsc>
            <c01 level="series" id="c01">
                <did>
                    <unittitle label="Contents: ">Correspondence by correspondent (no
                        1-6)</unittitle>
                    <daogrp linktype="extended">
                        <daoloc label="reference"
                            href="http://digitalcollections.library.leiden.edu//.html"
                            linktype="locator"/>
                    </daogrp>
                </did>
                <c02 level="item" id="c01.1">
                    <did>
                        <unitid type="EAD">1</unitid>
                        <unittitle label="Contents: ">Van Gent</unittitle>
```

Comment: it would help if you would provide a minimal XML input for us to play with.

Comment: Sorry, I must have forgotten to include it: https://i.imgur.com/Hs01kCQ.png

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual XML used, not an image of a visual representation, please? Also can you say exactly what you want to sort by? Thanks!

Comment: Done, and I want to sort by the unittitles in ascending alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have nested `xsl:for-each` here, just use the one....

```
<xsl:for-each select="ead/archdesc/dsc/c01/c02">
   <xsl:sort select="did/unittitle" />
   <li><xsl:value-of select="did/unittitle"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not sort the full list of titles in ascending order. my output is still the same as the one shown in my question.